# Search 2 postgres array_agg to find same item(s)

Tags: arrays, postgresql, subquery

I have 2 array_agg, a "search criteria" and a "list of all":

The codes I use to get the array_agg:

"search criteria"

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT n_id) as agg_n FROM pn WHERE n_id IN (100,101)
```

Result:

```
{100,101}
```

"list of all"

```
SELECT p_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT n_id) AS agg_n_2 FROM pn GROUP BY p_id
```

Result:

```
1 | {100,101}
2 | {100,101,102}
3 | {100,102}
4 | {101,103}
5 | {100,101,102,103}
```

The subqueries works fine and well. If I ask for it to return all of p_id that has n_id both 100 AND 101 (as per the request). It will only return `1`, when it should return `1,2,5`. If my request was just `{100}`, it will not return anything and I need it to return `1,2,3,5`

The full SQL is below. How can I do what I need? I know that the first 2 subqueries above should be correct but how do I structure the overall query?

```
WITH pn_o AS (SELECT p_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT n_id) AS agg_n FROM pn GROUP BY p_id),
      n_o AS (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT n_id) as agg_n_2 FROM pn WHERE n_id IN (100)) 
SELECT p_id FROM pn WHERE pn_o.agg_n = (SELECT n.agg_n_2 FROM n_o);
```

I've tried = and I've tried IN (which throws an error). I can't use ANY because it is not an OR criteria but an AND.

An example of the pn table (it has only 2 columns and both n_id and p_id are different foreign keys):

```
p_id | n_id
-----+-----
100  | 100
100  | 101
100  | 102
100  | 103
101  | 100
101  | 102
101  | 105
```

What I'm trying to find is the p_id that has association with the n_id be it 1 or more n_ids.

If there is a better statement I can use, it would be great too.

Thanks.
Desmond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just after I typed this question I found the answer. I've tested it and it works.

So for anyone who wants to do this using 1 statement, this is it.

```
WITH pn_o AS (SELECT p_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT n_id) AS agg_n FROM pn GROUP BY p_id),
     n_o AS (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT n_id) as agg_n_2 FROM pn WHERE n_id IN (100)) 
SELECT p_id FROM pn WHERE pn_o.agg_n @> (SELECT n.agg_n_2 FROM n_o);
```

`@>` is contains

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-array.html